# How to access a GitHub issue comment body using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

This is how you setup the action triggers for GitHub issue comments in `.github/workflows/main.yml`:

```
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited]
```

I *assume* that I can also read the issue comment inside `main.yml` and pass it as an input argument to my action.

How do I actually read the issue comment `body`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For both event types:

`- run: echo ${{ github.event.comment.body }}`

For `edited` only; get comment body before edit:

`- run: echo ${{ github.event.changes.body.from }}`

You can also add [one extra job](https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log-file) to your workflow while you work on it...

```
jobs:
 dump:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - name: $github
    run:   echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
    env:
     GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}

 # ...
```

...so you can easily see all kind of data related to triggered event.

Comment: please see the other answer on why you should never "echo ${{ github.event.comment.body }}" for security reasons.

Answer (score 7):

You should not run `echo ${{ github.event.comment.body }}`, because it potentially causes shell injection, which allows attackers do arbitrary code execution.

Run instead:

```yaml
- name: print body
  env:
    BODY: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
  run: echo "$BODY"
```

Worth reading: https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-untrusted-input/#remediation